# A ruby gem for drawing border for an Excel cell

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am using `gem spreadsheet`. But it has no option for drawing border around a cell. Which ruby gem has the support for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look this one gem:
[RubyXL](https://github.com/weshatheleopard/rubyXL#wrappers-for-accessing-cell-properties)

It works with cell's colors and borders too